# On the usage of “nether”

Tags: word-usage

While looking  for the origin of the the suffix of terms like [underneath](https://www.etymonline.com/word/underneath) and [beneath](https://www.etymonline.com/word/beneath?ref=etymonline_crossreference) I’ve found that it derives from “*neoðan "below, down, from below," from Proto-Germanic niþar "lower, farther down, down*" from which the current term  “***[nether](https://www.etymonline.com/word/nether?ref=etymonline_crossreference)***”

“Nether” appears to be an uncommon term, but dictionaries seem  to contradict each other about its usage:

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nether)  describe “nether” as “old fashioned”,

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nether)  defines its usage as “humorous”, while

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nether) doesn’t mention  any specific   issue and  shows a number of current usage examples.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nether&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnether%3B%2Cc0) appears to suggest that the term usage is not significantly lower than a century ago, so what is the exact current usage of “nether”?

Is it just literary or formal? Does it have humorous connotations? Is it actually old-fashioned as suggested above?

Comment: It's "humorous" precisely *because* it's "old-fashioned*. Most likely if you analyse the hits in Google Books and compare recent instances with those from a century ago you'll find that a relatively high proportion of the more recent ones are for the collocation ***nether regions*** - usually a facetious / euphemistic alternative to ***private parts*** (i.e. - the pubic area).

Comment: ...see [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nether+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cnether%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnether%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20millstone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20garments%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20regions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20lip%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20millstones%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20end%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20parts%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20limbs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnether%20mill%3B%2Cc0) which appears to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - so  “nether regions” sounds funnier than “lower regions” referring to private parts.

Comment: In Victorian times, some English people were so prudish that trousers were referred to as 'nether garments'. I have seen 'nether region' used to  mean 'hell'. Wikipedia helpfully reminds us not to confuse that phrase with 'Netherlands'.

Comment: The Netherlands are, however, a valid example of the use of  *nether*. They are low-lying and similar terms using different words are used for approximately the same region, such as the Low Countries. This is discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Countries . There are also several place-names in England, often contrasted with Upper or similar terms. For example, Nether Wallop https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nether_Wallop contrasted with Over Wallop and Middle Wallop.

Answer (score 5):

It is literary and tends to be used only in certain expressions.

The iWeb corpus has only 5 030 instances of "nether + noun", of which more than half are "nether world", "nether region(s)" or "nether portal".

Contrast this with 1 218 129 instances of "lower + noun".

Answer (score 2):

**nether** [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nether) Now chiefly literary. Sometimes humorous.  It is still used. Usually not used formally. Quaintly old-fashioned!

> The nether part of something is the lowest part of it, the bottom. If
>   you’re having, ahem, trouble in the toilet, you might want to go talk
>   to the doc about your nether parts.
>
> You might find the word nether in old books where "the nether world"
>   could mean the world under the earth’s surface, like in Dante’s
>   Inferno where he travels through hell, under the earth, before
>   climbing up to paradise in the heavens. If you look closely you can
>   hear the word nether in the word we normally use now: beneath.
>
> lower “gnawed his nether lip”
>
> located below or beneath something else “nether garments”
>
> low literal meanings; being at or having a relatively small elevation
>   or upward extension
>
> dwelling beneath the surface of the earth “nether regions”
>
> infernal being of the underworld

As in:

1986   R. M. Sunter *Patronage Politics in Scotl*.   ... in the Nether-ward of Lanarkshire.

and

1990   *Independent*    Football is a part of the nether-culture of English life with which its ruling classes are least familiar.

and

1993   *Clothes Show Mag.*    There have been as many names for knickers over the years as there are styles available in the shops... small clothes; nether garments; long johns, [etc.].

and

1994   *R. Davies Cunning Man*    All the beauty and diablerie of that great player had been lost, and only the mannerisms—grunting, eye-flashing, and gnawing the nether lip—remained.

and lastly

1992   M. Blonsky Amer. *Mythologies*    The media tell the ancient tale of the city as corrupt and its nether parts as the womb of evil.